# Beta-Reduction exercise with pairs in Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm doing some simple exercise about Lambda Calculus but i have doubt about this beta-reduction.

Let $$<u,v>= \lambda p((p)u)v$$ a pair in Lambda Calculus.

Prove that for every lambda term M you have that:
$$ (<M,u>) <M,v>  \simeq_{\beta} (((M)M)v)u$$

Comment: There's nothing wrong here. The only glaring issue I see is that your first step is not a $\beta$-reduction, even though you've marked it as such.

Comment: Oh thank you , I will correct now! So I will also change the question in an answer

Comment: Note that on the first step you are implicitly using an $\alpha$-reduction as well as substituting values in, if you'd want to mark that.

Comment: Ok thank you again, I pretty new in the lambda calculus world...

Answer (score 1):

To prove that you can follow this steps:
$$(<M,u>) <M,v>  \simeq_{\alpha} (\lambda p((p)M)u) \space \lambda q((q)M)v \\ \simeq_{\beta} ((\lambda q((q)M)v)M)u\\ \simeq_{\beta} ((M)M)v)u$$

Q.E.D.